# ZipObject.async function not work in browser

Tags: javascript

I've met a strange problem.

I have a piece of code:

```js
var jszip = new JSZip();
jszip.loadAsync(excel).then(
    zip => {
        Object.keys(zip.files).forEach(filename => {
            // ... check type
            zip.files[filename].async(fileType).then(data => {
                // can not execute here in browser
            }
        }
    }
)
```

This code can execute in Vue project with node env, but not execute in browser.

In browser, zip.files[filename].async(fileType) always Pending ... Where did I go wrong?

But the strange thing is, my previous version of the project works this way.

I've tried push in promises:

```js
const promises = [];

Object.keys(zip.files).forEach(filename => {
    // ... check type
    promises.push(zip.files[filename].async(fileType));
}

Promise.all(promises).then(data => {
    // ...
});
```

But it still not work.

I couldn't search for a solution...